Can I download / buy Cambridge English Corpus / Cambridge Learner Corpus? Where to download these corpus?
I seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_English_Corpus .

Can I download / buy Cambridge English Corpus / Cambridge Learner Corpus? Where to download these corpus?

Corpus of Contemporary American English https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/

You can use this tool https://skell.sketchengine.eu/#result?lang=en&query=my%20name%20is&f=concordance
Quote

How can I access the corpus?
• Sketch Engine – provides several standard tools for corpus queries
(word lists, word sketch, sketch diff, text types) as well as some
enabled features for the CLC
• Usernames/passwords available for researchers and teachers on
request:
http://languageresearch.cambridge.org/academicresearch-request-form
• Comprehensive user guides available for Sketch Engine, CLC and
Corpus Query Language (CQL)

source https://www.latl.leeds.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/sites/49/2019/07/CLC-demo-final.pdf
For full access, need paid for subscription.
